# Consuming WCF service from dynamic send port in biztalk over https and in PUT mode

Tags: wcf, https, biztalk, put, biztalk-orchestrations

I want to consume a PUT WCF service over a https connection from a BizTalk orchestration dynamic send port so far I am using this code in my message assignment shape

```
XMLDocumentOutput(WCF.MaxReceivedMessageSize)= 2147483647;

XMLDocumentOutput(WCF.HttpMethodAndUrl) = @"<BtsHttpUrlMapping>  <Operation Name='RestPUT' Method='PUT'  /> </BtsHttpUrlMapping>";
XMLDocumentOutput(WCF.TransportClientCredentialType) = "Transport";
XMLDocumentOutput(WCF.SecurityMode)="Transport";

XMLDocumentOutput(WCF.UseSSO) = false;
XMLDocumentOutput(WCF.HttpHeaders) = "Authorization: Basic AbScSfKajfsalAbScSfKajfsalAbScSfKajfsal=";

PortName(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.Address) = "https://example.com/url/url2";
PortName(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.TransportType)="WCF-WSHttp";
```

URL: https://example.com/url/url2
Method: PUT

I am not able to consume service and getting following error
   The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was ''.
   HTTP auth header not found

The server is using basic authentication.

Thanks

Comment: Cannot believe that SO users could not answer this question. :(

Answer (score 0):

I ended up calling a C# method and making HttpWebRequest. Still would love to know if anybody has love for it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you resolved your issue since posting your question?
I'd think you would need to replace:

```
XMLDocumentOutput(WCF.HttpMethodAndUrl) = @"<BtsHttpUrlMapping>  <Operation Name='RestPUT' Method='PUT'  /> </BtsHttpUrlMapping>";
XMLDocumentOutput(WCF.TransportClientCredentialType) = "Transport";
```

with:

```
XMLDocumentOutput(WCF.Action) = "PUT";
XMLDocumentOutput(WCF.TransportClientCredentialType) = "Basic";
```

If you were to manually configure a non-dynamic send port using the BizTalk Server Administration Console dialogs, WCF-WSHttp or other, you will see that the dialog labels would match the WCF properties in the orchestration expression dialog.

Not sure though if you should add the Basic auth credentials using the WCF.HttpHeaders, since the admin console dialog doesn't expose this.

You may need to use

```
XMLDocumentOutput(WCF.UserName) = "<username here>";
XMLDocumentOutput(WCF.Password) = "<password here>";
```